# installing ssh in the docker containers

Tags: unix, docker, dockerfile

i have a ubuntu machine that hosts a docker container.
    and in the docker container i am running a web service which must validate 
    the user's password with the docker host's /etc/password.

my view is to ssh into docker host from the docker container.
    so when i run command ssh in the docker container its saying ssh not found.
    so,basically ssh is not installed in the container.
    how can i install ssh in the container.
    is there any way to accomplish this scenario?.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, as part of the image file you'll simply have to install openssh-server:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

The problem then is that traditionally, a running docker container will only run a single command. You can get around this problem by using something like supervisord. There's an example in the docker docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/

Your dockerfile might look like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER examples@docker.com

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server apache2 supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /var/lock/apache2 /var/run/apache2 /var/run/sshd /var/log/supervisor

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

EXPOSE 22 80
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Your supervisord.conf might look something like this:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:sshd]
command=/usr/sbin/sshd -D

[program:apache2]
command=/bin/bash -c "source /etc/apache2/envvars && exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND"
```