# Running a Docker command in the background?

Tags: docker

How would you run a daemon or background process in Docker? I've seen some suggestions, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40802627/247542) that launches supervisor from CMD.

However, I'm trying to test a server configuration tool that connects via SSH. So I need to launch the SSH daemon in the background, and then run my `tool.sh` to test connecting via SSH to its own container. I need to monitor my tool's output in order to verify it's working. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Is there any way to make a RUN command run in the background, like `RUN /usr/sbin/sshd -D &` or would I have to have some wrapper script launched from CMD that does something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/sshd -D
tool.sh
```

Comment: `RUN` commands execute at image **build** time. The only way to start processes at runtime is via `CMD` (and `ENTRYPOINT`). You want to do something like what you've suggested, but you'll want to get rid of the `-D` argument because you *want* ssh to go into the background, and `-D` prevents that.

Comment: Or you can do another thing. You will run `sshd` daemon using `CMD`/`ENTRYPOINT` in the Dockerfile like @larsks said before. And next after starting the container, you can execute your `tool.sh` script into your running container using `$ docker exec -i[t]...` command. Hope this will work.

Comment: Is there a specific reason your test driver and the system under test have to be the same container?  The easiest answer to "how do I run two processes in Docker" is "in two separate containers", and that's doubly true if one process is already expecting to make a network connection to the other.

Comment: @DavidMaze makes a very good point, and running 2 containers is probably the solution that is most consistent with the "one job" philisophy of lightweight virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a daemon inside a docker container the same as you would on a bare metal linux machine. The only hard part is getting it to start without the nice runlevel scripts to help.

How about this:

```shell
#!/bin/sh

function run_script() {
    ssh_pids=0
    while [ ${ssh_pids} -lt 1 ]; do
        sleep 5
        ssh_pids=$(pgrep sshd | wc -l)
    done
    test.sh
}

run_script &
sshd -D > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I've used this trick before to do what you describe, and it's worked OK. It will just background the call to `run_script` and proceed to start SSHD in non-daemon mode, piping it to `/dev/null`. Meanwhile, `run_script` polls for `sshd`; when it finds it, it quits polling and runs `test.sh`, which should still have the terminal as it's `stdout`. you'll probably need to use some external kill signal to stop the whole thing, once `test.sh` is done.

If you don't like this tomfoolery, the other option would be to do as you described: write a wrapper script to use as the CMD/ENTRYPOINT, and have it start SSHD *without* the debug flag, and then start `test.sh`.

The advantage of doing it with the script I posted is that the container will stick around after `test.sh` is finished, so you can log in and poke around, while also making your script wait until the daemon is running.